# django view/model как правильно сделать запрос используя чистый sql запрос

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-model

Пытаюсь в вьюшке использовать чистый sql запрос к модели(model) данных в данном случае (таблица app_table), но выходит ошибка: **не целочисленная константа в ORDER BY**

```
from django.db import connection       # для работы с чистым sql в django 
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     cursor.execute("SELECT 'ZavKod', 'summa' from app_table ORDER BY 'summa' ")   # <-- ошибка хз
     row = cursor.fetchall()
```

содержимое таблицы примерно такое (тип данных поля summa: float/double precision):

| ZavKod | summa |
| --- | --- |
| 3004025429 | -3230285.76 |
| 3004061108 | -895348.95 |

PS: в datagrip/ide для работы с sql данный sql-запрос работает норм, но в логике django/view/model вылезает такая ошибка

Comment: В Постгрессе одинарная кавычка используется для обрамления строковых литералов, а ни фига не для имён полей. Уберите их вообще, все шесть - нафига вы их вставили?

Comment: без одинарных кавычек ошибка выходит: столбец "zavkod" не существует, тоже грешил на них но одня фигня ошибка :/

Comment: Ну почитай ты наконец документацию-то! на сей раз - о регистрозависимости имён объектов.

Comment: регистрозависимости имён объектов - ого первый раз слышу такое ) окей почитаю

Comment: Спасибо за направление Akina